# Add id and class attributes to xml

Tags: html, xml, dom, xml-parsing, dtd

I want to use standard HTML id and class attributes in my xml data. I want to do so to be able to aggregate elements in different groups and combinations. It is OK if I use HTML DTD in my xml document. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the question? You can use attributes as you like in XML. In which sense would you need them to be “HTML attributes”, and what would you use a DTD for? If you think you could use an HTML DTD, then apparently your XML would *be* HTML (XHTML).

Comment: I want to use id and class attributes in the special sense they are being used in HTML. I mean I should be able to access XML elements by using getElementById and getElementbyClass functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use attributes as you like in XML. If you wish them to be taken as “HTML attributes”, so that processing rules in HTML specifications apply to them, you need to declare the relevant elements as being in the HTML namespace. DTDs have nothing to do with this. Example (note that the `script` element needs the namespace too):

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="dummystyle.css"?>
<doc>
<foo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="id" class="class">dummy</foo>
<script xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
console.log(document.getElementById('id').innerHTML);
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('class')[0].innerHTML);
</script>
</doc>
```

You can also use the `xmlns` attribute on an element that encloses the relevant element, to avoid repeating the attribute. But then *all* elements inside it will be interpreter in terms of HTML, if their names coincide with HTML element names.

Comment: Thanks for your excellent answer though XML attributes can also be made special ID attributes by using DTD like this:`<!DOCTYPE doc [
<!ATTLIST elementname attributename ID #IMPLIED>
]>`

Answer (score 0):

There are no DTD police that check XML vocabulary designs for OKness, so you are almost certainly OK no matter what you do.  It's hard to explain what what you want to do is OK, though, without any understanding of why you are worried that it might not be OK.  Here is a sort of scattershot approach to explaining why you don't need to worry.

Legally, the use of the HTML DTD defined by W3C is governed by whatever license the W3C has put on it; it's pretty much certain that there is no legal barrier to your reusing the DTD, or parts of it (HTML 4.01 and XHTML 1.0 have carefully modularized DTDs designed to enable reuse).  But I am not a lawyer and this is not legal advice.

Morally, there is no objection to using id and class attributes in your vocabulary with the same meaning they have in HTML.  Some may wrinkle their nose, but their concerns are likely to be aesthetic or political, not moral.

Technically, if you just want to use id and class attributes, and not any larger portion of the HTML DTD, it's unlikely that reusing the HTML DTD will bring you much advantage.  The modularization is complex, and making it work involves a lot of fiddly work of the kind that appeals to some people and not so much to other people.   So the simplest and most common way to reuse for individual HTML attributes will be just to declare attributes of appropriate names in your schema, and specify in your documentation that they have the meanings given them by HTML.